# Flutter: can I use setState() with a BLoC architecture?

Tags: flutter, bloc

My understanding of state management is that calling `setState()` alone opens up a variety of messy issues, code files become huge and difficult to debug, and it prevents holding a sensible structure to a project. In cases where the widget's appearance changes slightly, it makes little sense to have a complex architecture like BLoC or ScopedModel just to show/hide a widget (for example). However, the way I have understood it is that you can't mix `setState()` and an architecture together, otherwise what's the point of the architecture?

Let's use BLoC for this question (simply because I happen to be using it), specifically [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc). Let's say I have this super simple example code:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  void createState() {
    return _MyWidgetState();
  }
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget>() {
  bool _isShowing = false;
  MyBloc bloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.init();
    bloc = MyBloc();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder(
      bloc: bloc,
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(state.myText),
            if (_isShowing)
              Text("Button has been pressed!"),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Show label"),
              onTap: () => setState(() => _isShowing = true),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Run event"),
              onTap: () => bloc.add(NewEvent()),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

In the crude example above, is it right/acceptable to mix the BLoC pattern with `setState()`? Why would I not use BLoC to handle showing the `Text` widget? Where do I draw the line? What are the pros/cons? Is there a performance difference?

Note: I'm not looking for "just merge the two `Text` widgets together" answers. I'm looking for purely architectural perspectives.

Comment: AFAIK: BLoC is architecture to separate business logic from the UI part. You can combine setState with the bloc if needed anytime.

Answer (score 35):

You can.

Architecture like scoped_model/bloc/etc aren't about removing calls to setState. 
They are about separating concerns and simplifying the implementation

You *can* and *should* use setState when it makes sense to use it, such as with animations.

To begin with, even these architectures use setState. You just don't see it, but it's there